# How to implement rotation algorithm for cube in OpenGL Java?

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

Here is my code for created a cube in OpenGL with Java, how to implement algorithm for rotation over `Ox`, `Oy` and `Oz` axis without using predefinition function. For example how to rotate it over origin point or another point.

```
import java.awt.DisplayMode;
import javax.media.opengl.GL2;
import javax.media.opengl.GLAutoDrawable;
import javax.media.opengl.GLCapabilities;
import javax.media.opengl.GLEventListener;
import javax.media.opengl.GLProfile;
import javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas;
import javax.media.opengl.glu.GLU;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import com.jogamp.opengl.util.FPSAnimator;

public class Cube implements GLEventListener {

   public static DisplayMode dm, dm_old;
   private GLU glu = new GLU();
   private float rquad = 0.0f;

   @Override
   public void display( GLAutoDrawable drawable ) {

      final GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
      gl.glClear(GL2.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL2.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
      gl.glLoadIdentity();
      gl.glTranslatef( 0f, 0f, -5.0f ); 

      // Rotate The Cube On X, Y & Z
      gl.glRotatef(rquad, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f); 

      //giving different colors to different sides
      gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_QUADS); // Start Drawing The Cube
      gl.glColor3f(1f,0f,0f); //red color
      gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f); // Top Right Of The Quad (Top)
      gl.glVertex3f( -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f); // Top Left Of The Quad (Top)
      gl.glVertex3f( -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f ); // Bottom Left Of The Quad (Top)
      gl.glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f ); // Bottom Right Of The Quad (Top)

      gl.glColor3f( 0f,1f,0f ); //green color
      gl.glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f ); // Top Right Of The Quad
      gl.glVertex3f( -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f ); // Top Left Of The Quad
      gl.glVertex3f( -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f ); // Bottom Left Of The Quad
      gl.glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f ); // Bottom Right Of The Quad 

      gl.glColor3f( 0f,0f,1f ); //blue color
      gl.glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f ); // Top Right Of The Quad (Front)
      gl.glVertex3f( -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f ); // Top Left Of The Quad (Front)
      gl.glVertex3f( -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f ); // Bottom Left Of The Quad
      gl.glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f ); // Bottom Right Of The Quad 

      gl.glColor3f( 1f,1f,0f ); //yellow (red + green)
      gl.glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f ); // Bottom Left Of The Quad
      gl.glVertex3f( -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f ); // Bottom Right Of The Quad
      gl.glVertex3f( -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f ); // Top Right Of The Quad (Back)
      gl.glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f ); // Top Left Of The Quad (Back)

      gl.glColor3f( 1f,0f,1f ); //purple (red + green)
      gl.glVertex3f( -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f ); // Top Right Of The Quad (Left)
      gl.glVertex3f( -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f ); // Top Left Of The Quad (Left)
      gl.glVertex3f( -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f ); // Bottom Left Of The Quad
      gl.glVertex3f( -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f ); // Bottom Right Of The Quad 

      gl.glColor3f( 0f,1f, 1f ); //sky blue (blue +green)
      gl.glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f ); // Top Right Of The Quad (Right)
      gl.glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f ); // Top Left Of The Quad
      gl.glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f ); // Bottom Left Of The Quad
      gl.glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f ); // Bottom Right Of The Quad
      gl.glEnd(); // Done Drawing The Quad
      gl.glFlush();

      rquad -= 0.15f;
   }

   @Override
   public void dispose( GLAutoDrawable drawable ) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   }

   @Override
   public void init( GLAutoDrawable drawable ) {

      final GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
      gl.glShadeModel( GL2.GL_SMOOTH );
      gl.glClearColor( 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f );
      gl.glClearDepth( 1.0f );
      gl.glEnable( GL2.GL_DEPTH_TEST );
      gl.glDepthFunc( GL2.GL_LEQUAL );
      gl.glHint( GL2.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL2.GL_NICEST );
   }

   @Override
   public void reshape( GLAutoDrawable drawable, int x, int y, int width, int height ) {

      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      final GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
      if( height lt;= 0 )
         height = 1;

      final float h = ( float ) width / ( float ) height;
      gl.glViewport( 0, 0, width, height );
      gl.glMatrixMode( GL2.GL_PROJECTION );
      gl.glLoadIdentity();

      glu.gluPerspective( 45.0f, h, 1.0, 20.0 );
      gl.glMatrixMode( GL2.GL_MODELVIEW );
      gl.glLoadIdentity();
   }

   public static void main( String[] args ) {

      final GLProfile profile = GLProfile.get( GLProfile.GL2 );
      GLCapabilities capabilities = new GLCapabilities( profile );

      // The canvas
      final GLCanvas glcanvas = new GLCanvas( capabilities );
      Cube cube = new Cube();

      glcanvas.addGLEventListener( cube );
      glcanvas.setSize( 400, 400 );

      final JFrame frame = new JFrame ( " Multicolored cube" );
      frame.getContentPane().add( glcanvas );
      frame.setSize( frame.getContentPane().getPreferredSize() );
      frame.setVisible( true );
      final FPSAnimator animator = new FPSAnimator(glcanvas, 300,true);

      animator.start();
   }
}
```

Comment: By "without using predefinition function" I'm assuming you mean without using `glRotatef()`. If that is the case, then I don't follow why you're not using a newer version of OpenGL. However what you want to do is create a rotation matrix.

Comment: yes, without using glRotatef()

Comment: Like I said before [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix).

Comment: see [Understanding 4x4 homogenous transform matrices](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214)

Comment: At first, please use JOGL 2.3.2 instead of an old version of JOGL 2. Secondly, use GLU.createGLU(GL) instead of "new GLU()" in order to get a more capable GLU instance (you risk to get a UnsupportedOperationException with your current code in some cases). Thirdly, you can build your own matrices and use glLoadMatrix or use the programmable pipeline with shaders. You can ask your JOGL specific questions on our official forum: http://forum.jogamp.org

Comment: By the way, passing 300 when creating an FPSAnimator is a bit dumb as it will never reach this framerate without disabling the vertical synchronization. Rather use a plain Animator.